# Getting the text of the clicked element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following divs that are grouped into three layers. I need to get the text of the clicked element like for example they clicked "123" I will be able to record it.

```
    <div class="Div1st">

      <div class="Di2ndv">
        <div class="Div3rd">123</div>
        <div class="Div3rd">abc</div>
      </div>

      <div class="Div2nd">
        <div class="Div3rd">def</div>
        <div class="Div3rd">456</div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

"Class Names" are only meant to clearly show the hierarchy(layers) of the divs

I tried doing the code below but it only works on until 2nd Div. If I went deeper like in 3rd div it doesn't show anything.

```
    $(".Div1st > div").click(function (e) {
        alert($(this).find('div').text());
    });
```

Comment: If you want to bind the handler to `.3rdDiv`, you should do that. Right now you are binding it to `.2ndDiv`.

Comment: Note that class names should not start with numbers, it's invalid based on the standard.

Comment: Jasper.. Yes I know that. But I used it that way to clearly show the layers of the Divs.

Comment: All the invalid class names and IDs on this page are making me cringe :)

Comment: Jasper.. I'm sorry I just want to make sure that you can understand the code at first glance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use:

```
$(".1stDiv > div")
```

jQuery only gets the children elements of the .1stDiv., which would be the 2ndDiv.  To get all divs, you would use:

```
$(".1stDiv div")
```

I would of course not recommend, using $(".1stDiv div").  Instead, you should give the div elements that you want to click a class, and use the following:

```
$(".clickableDiv", ".1stDiv")
```

**Update:** I would recommend this: $(".clickableDiv", **"#1stDiv"**).  This will give you better performance, because IDs in jQuery give much better performance than classes (they natively use document.GetElementById).  Given the '#1stDiv' context element will only have jQuery search in that div.  This will give good performance.

Comment: Or if you want to target only 3rd level `<div />` elements you could do: `$(".1stDiv > div > div")`. Also note that starting a class name with a number is not valid.

Comment: thank you!!! this solved the problem I've been going on and on for minutes now...

Comment: Jasper I tried that but it didn't record the text I needed

Comment: @Jaeger you probably didn't remove the `.find('div')` from `$(this).find('div').text()`. Which is necessary because the selected div has no children when directly selecting the third level div elements... also, don't expect any type of output from `$(this).find('div').text()`, you need to store the value in a variable or do something with it.

Comment: Again, with your suggestion to use an ID instead of class as the initial selection, IDs should not start with a digit as per the spec.

Comment: @pathachiever11 if you really care about performance, you should use `$('#1stDiv').find('.clickableDiv')`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon That's HTML5, if you know your audience is all on new browsers then you'd be good to go, but HTML4 was not so forgiving. There's probably a couple/few more years of needing to support the old style for people who don't update.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Since the OP is binding the click event, using the context element should be good. I'm just encouraging the practice of using IDs where possible for performance

Comment: @Pathachiever11 and i'm saying, performancewise, that `.find` is better than `context selector`, nothing agaisnt your code :)

Comment: @Jasper I was going to mention that, but then I figured the OP used #1stDiv for an example. Most developers shy away from beginning ids from digits, large letters, keeping it camelcase.  At least the ones I've worked with.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon haha, no worries, I thought that the context element gave better performance.  I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
    <div class="1stDiv ">

      <div class="2ndDiv ">
        <div class="3rdDiv ">123</div>
        <div class="3rdDiv ">abc</div>
      </div>

      <div class="2ndDiv ">
        <div class="3rdDiv ">def</div>
        <div class="3rdDiv ">456</div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

then

```
    $("div").click(function (e) {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: Yes this is possible but I don't like the idea of giving them all the same classes. What If I have 100 divs that needs to be recorded? It will just more typing and I don't like that..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `target`:

```
$(".1stDiv > div").click(function (e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: target is not the solution, i tried using it before and it's not behaving the way I want to. Even if you just highlight the text it will be recorded.

Comment: try to use the code I posted here and just highlight 123 and abc.. It will show you what I meant

Comment: @Jaeger either I don't understand what you want or you did something wrong : http://jsfiddle.net/j89fN/